# What is so special about the least norm solution in case of an undetermined system of equations

Tags: least-squares, svd

In particular this is the go to approach in case of solving a least squares problem that lacks a unique solution, how does being the closest point to the origin among all the solutions make it any better than the others?

Comment: The method you describe is so arbitrary that I wonder whether you could provide a credible reference.  It would be less arbitrary to apply this criterion to the *standardized* coefficients.

Comment: The least norm solution is the one provided through singular value decomposition whenever one calculates the pseudo-inverse.

Comment: @whuber This is a standard topic taught in most linear algebra courses. I think what's missing in the question is how this mathematical topic relates to statistics. Perhaps this should be migrated to math.stackexchange if no additional information is given?

Comment: For example, Gilbert Strang does this exact thing near the beginning of this video lecture: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-065-matrix-methods-in-data-analysis-signal-processing-and-machine-learning-spring-2018/video-lectures/lecture-11-minimizing-2016x2016-subject-to-ax-b/

Comment: This is the solution you will find if you regularize the problem as ridge regression ... showing why it is natural.

Comment: @ericperkerson Well I already posted this on math.stackexchange a few days ago and got no responses, @ kjetil b halvorsen thanks you for that addition it's really helpful :).